# Swagger openapi-gen generates the wrong responseType

Tags: angular, swagger, nestjs, openapi-generator

I tried to use ng-openapi-gen to generate the service for querying the backend, but the generated responseType is not the right one (I want it to be 'text').

In the backend, using nestJS, defined the following function:

```js
    @ApiResponse({
        status: 200,
        description: 'Get the name of the file after download',
        type: String
    })
    public async getCalibrationDownloadFilename(@Param('someId', new ParseIntPipe()) someId: number): Promise<string> {
        ...
    }
```

When using the command `ng-openapi-gen` in the frontend (Angular), it generates:

```js
calibrationCertificateControllerGetCalibrationDownloadFilename$Response(params: {
  someId: number;
}): Observable<StrictHttpResponse<string>> {

  const rb = new RequestBuilder(this.rootUrl, CalibrationSensorCertificationService.CalibrationCertificateControllerGetCalibrationDownloadFilenamePath, 'get');
  if (params) {
    rb.path('someId', params.someId, {});
  }

  return this.http.request(rb.build({
    responseType: 'json',
    accept: 'application/json'
  })).pipe(
    filter((r: any) => r instanceof HttpResponse),
    map((r: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      return r as StrictHttpResponse<string>;
    })
  );
}
```

The `responseType` is `json` instead of `text`.

If, in the backend, I remove the `type: String`, the `responseType` is set to `text`, but then the function return type becomes `Observable<StrictHttpResponse<void>>`.

I tried to set the type to `string`, and a `'string'` but then I get errors.

How to properly set-up swagger for generating a function which returns an observable of string, and set the responseType of the query to be 'text'?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @AmosIsaila I bypassed the issue by removing the swagger decorators for this function from the backend and wrote the frontend function myself